# Error previous definition of 'class Player' en C++

Tags: c++

Hola a todos tengo un problema con mi codigo compilaba bien no recuerdo que le movi y me da un error. Aqui les dejo mi codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

int main(){
   Player player1( 3, 10 );
   Enemy enemy1( 4, 10 );

   while( player1.receiveDamage( enemy1.inflictDamage() ) > 0 
      && enemy1.receiveDamage( player1.inflictDamage() ) > 0 ) {
      cout << "Player 1: ";
      player1.printLife();

      cout << "Enemy: ";
      enemy1.printLife();
   }
 }
```

Player.h

```
class Player{
public:
    Player( int, int );
    int inflictDamage();
    int receiveDamage( int );
    void printLife();
private:
    int attack;
    int life;
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#include "Player.h"

Player::Player( int ap, int lp ){
   attack = ap;
   life = lp;

   srand( time( 0 ) );
}

int Player::inflictDamage(){
   int damage = 0;
   int dice = 1 + rand() % 6;

   if( dice > 3 )
      damage = attack;
   else
      damage = 0;

  return damage;
}

int Player::receiveDamage( int damage ){
   return life -= damage;
}

void Player::printLife(){
   cout << life << endl;
```

}

Enemy.h

```
#include "Player.h"

class Enemy : public Player{
   public:
       Enemy( int, int );
};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy( int ap, int lp ) : Player( ap, lp ){

   srand( time( 0 ) );
}
```

Estos son los errores que me salen:

> [Error] redefinition of 'class Player'
>   [Error] previous definition of 'class Player'

---

**Editado:**

Entiendo lo de las guardas pero necesito a los dos objetos player y enemy en el main para que se "peleen", creo que estoy usando mal lo de heredar y ahora me sale otro error.

```
pelea.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `Player::receiveDamage(int)'
```

es el mismo error con todas la funciones de Player.cpp.

Pd. ya puse los `#ifndef #define`en donde me faltaba.

Comment: ¿ Como estás compilando el proyecto ? ¿ con un `Makefile` ? ¿ mediante línea de ordenes ? Indica la orden exacta que usas para generar el ejecutable final.

Comment: Ya lo resolví volvi a hacer todo de nuevo y compilo bien no se que tenia pero ya funciona gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has incluido `Player.hpp` dos veces. `main.cpp` incluye a `Player.hpp`, y a `Enemy.hpp`, y `Enermy.hpp` include a `Player.hpp` de nuevo, lo que significa, que `main.cpp`  está viendo `Player.hpp` dos veces.

Lo que no tienes puesto son guardas:

```
// Player.hpp
#ifndef PLAYER_HPP
#define PLAYER_HPP

// El nombre elegido para el ifndef/define no tiene porqué coincidir
// con el nombre del fichero. Simplemente, no debe de coincidir con
// ningún otro define que tengas en el programa. La manera más
// sencilla, es hacer que el nombre del define coincida con el del 
// fichero, dado que no vas a tener dos ficheros iguales, no vas a
// tener dos defines iguales. El uso de mayúsculas es sencillamente
// costumbre. Los define se suelen poner en mayúscula, y en el código
// real, no se suele utilizar ninguna variable ni función que esté
// entera en mayúscula. De esta forma, con solo ver el nombre, sabes
// si se trata de un define o no.

class Player{
public:
    Player( int, int );
    int inflictDamage();
    int receiveDamage( int );
    void printLife();
private:
    int attack;
    int life;
};

#endif
```

A esta pareja de directivas de preprocesador se le llaman **guardas**, porque protegen al fichero (de no ser incluído dos veces). Si `PLAYER_HPP` no está definido (la primera vez que se incluye no lo está), se define. La segunda vez que se incluye, al estar ya definido, se salta el `if`, y el código desde ahí hasta el `#endif` no se incluye.

Todas las cabeceras, todo fichero `.h`, `.hpp`, etc, todo fichero que se vaya a incluir en otro sitio, debe tener guardas como costumbre sana.

Los `.cpp` y ficheros que no se incluyan, no necesitan guardas, dado que
no se incluyen, valga la redundancia.

Lo mismo desde hacer con `Enemy.hpp`, por supuesto.

Comment: `pelea.cpp` no es un fichero que hayas mencionado en tu pregunta. ¿Cómo estás compilando? Quizás no estás compilando el fichero `Player.cpp`.

Comment: pelea.cpp es main pues siempre compilo el main uso devc++

Comment: Tienes que asegurarte de que todos los ficheros están siendo compilados, no solo `Pelea.cpp`, sino también `Player.cpp` y `Enemy.cpp`.

Comment: Como complemento quisiera añadir que existe una directiva (no estándar) del compilador de Microsoft que actúa como las [guardas de inclusión (ing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard): [`#pragma once`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Answer (score 0):

Yo inclui lo siguiente

```
#pragma once
```

en cada clase fuera del main, en mi caso en cada pestana con la extension ___.h